# is it possible to execute html page's javascript to execute code in developer tool

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

is it possible to execute html page's javascript to execute code in developer tool and get result back. For eg highlighting the element block using developer tool and entering $0 in the console would give the element details..so would executing $0 in the web page's javascript will get the same result.

Comment: You can type Javascript code in the console and it will be executed just like Javascript in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup multiple "watch expressions" and step through code and see what they are at each step.